# Spring Cloud Config - Reading multiple property files from Git

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I am using Spring Boot 2, I have an application.yml for each service. Each application.yml defines common properties as well as specific properties per profile. I want to move on to Spring Cloud Config.

I would like each service to read properties from 4 property files, meaning for a service called "myService" with profile "dev", I want to be able to read from:

- config/myService/application-dev.yml (specific config for this service and this profile)
- config/myService/application.yml (specific config for this service no matter which profile)
- config/application-dev.yml (specific config for dev profile no matter which service)
- config/application.yml (shared config no matter which service, no matter which profile)

I created a directory config. There are subdirectories for each service.

However only 2 files are retrieved from git when myService is starting. A third file is retrieved through EncryptablePropertySourceConverter.
 The missing file is config/application.yml. See below myService log:

```
 10:27:42.535 [main] INFO  o.s.c.b.c.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration - Located property source: 
 10:54:20.449 [main] INFO  o.s.c.b.c.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration - Located property source: CompositePropertySource {name='configService', 
 propertySources=[MapPropertySource {name='configClient'}, 
 MapPropertySource {name='ssh://git@xxx:7999/qi/athena.git/config/myService/application-dev.yml'}, 
 MapPropertySource {name='ssh://git@xxx:7999/qi/athena.git/config/myService/application.yml'}]}
 ...
 10:54:27.141 [main] INFO  c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter - Converting PropertySource applicationConfig: [file:./config/application-dev.yml] 
 [org.springframework.boot.env.OriginTrackedMapPropertySource] to EncryptableMapPropertySourceWrapper
 ...
 10:55:01.469 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator - Environment myService has 2 property sources with 6 properties.
10:55:01.469 [main] INFO  o.s.c.b.c.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration - Located property source: CompositePropertySource {name='configService', 
propertySources=[MapPropertySource {name='configClient'}, 
MapPropertySource {name='ssh://git@xxx:7999/qi/athena.git/config/myService/application-dev.yml'}, 
MapPropertySource {name='ssh://git@xxx:7999/qi/athena.git/config/myService/application.yml'}
```

Config service - application.yml:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: config-server
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: ssh://git@xxx:7999/qi/athena.git
          clone-on-start: true
          search-paths: 'config/{application}'
          default-label: 'feature/ConfigServerDesign'
```

myService - bootstrap.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: myService
  cloud:
      config:
        uri: http://localhost:8888
        label: 'feature/ConfigServerDesign'
```

The two files config/myService/application.yml and config/myService/application-dev are read.

Also the shared config/application.yml is read.
https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_server.html#_sharing_configuration_with_all_applications
However the file config/application.yml is not read.

Is there a conflict between config/application.yml and config/myService/application.yml ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the content of the files that were not read.
If by mistake there is a property:

```
spring.profiles: some_profile
```

then application.yml file is not read.

Same if you have for example:

```
spring.profiles: prod
```

in an application-uat.yml file.

I guess this is the right behavior to ignore such files since this is an inconsistency or conflict.
However an error or warning message should have helped in this case instead of ignoring silently the file.